# Sessions always empty in database (Version 6.2.5)

Tags: grafana

I'm doing with the scale-up session management for Grafana. Luckily, In the new Grafana version (above 6.2) we store session in the database as default (https://grafana.com/docs/installation/configuration/#session)
Anyway, when I try to open many sessions and check the session storage in Mysql it always empty

```
mysql> select * from session;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

I realized that the connection session for each user will store in user_auth_token table.

```
mysql> select * from user_auth_token\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
             id: 1
        user_id: 2
     auth_token: 396dcbf78bbb5f40a52a2d63bdce8a0b0612c1e3381ad6d4c2ef81ee6a532b95
prev_auth_token: 396dcbf78bbb5f40a52a2d63bdce8a0b0612c1e3381ad6d4c2ef81ee6a532b95
     user_agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36
      client_ip: 133.237.7.76, 127.0.0.1
auth_token_seen: 1
        seen_at: 1562667883
     rotated_at: 1562667883
     created_at: 1562667883
     updated_at: 1562667883
*************************** 2. row ***************************
```

If I clear this data, the current session of user will be removed and he need to login again.
My question is "What's session table use in Grafana database" and "How we can check it?"
Thank you so much for your advice!

Comment: Session storage is no longer used

In 6.2 we completely removed the backend session storage since we replaced the previous login session implementation with an auth token. If you are using Auth proxy with LDAP an shared cached is used in Grafana so you might want configure [remote_cache] instead. If not Grafana will fallback to using the database as an shared cache. Sorry, my fault :)